# Qdisc pfifo_fast in linux and IP Precedence

Tags: linux, routing, qos, embedded

Im using a embedded Linux distribution for a router system. My goal is to prioritize some traffic with minimum delay. I have a WAN interface with a default `pfifo_fast qdisc` attached to it. I have read that this qdisc schedule traffic using TOS 4 bits field in datagram header but does it use IP Precedence bits too?. By default my linux distribution is marking for internal use via `ebtables` some traffic with `mark-or xxx` depending of the traffic the user wants to prioritize. Im guessing how the mark is used by the wan interface, its possible that there are some queues used internally by the WAN device and that this queues are independent of the `pfifo_fast qdisc`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing ATM driver source code i have discovered how packet mark is handled. `skb->mark` is checked in the `_xmit` function of the ATM interface to queue the frame in the regarding queue. The driver is from our chipset provider its not present in the Linux kernel.